# Segoe UI Symbol smiley is sometimes colorful, sometimes not

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, emoticons

I have the following problem with my smileys:

```
<!-- Displays a colorful smiley -->
<PivotItem Header="Add &#x1F636;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol">

<!-- Displays a black & white smiley -->
<TextBlock Text="&#x1F636;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
```

How do I get a nice colorful smiley in a TextBlock? Is it a particularity of the TextBlock? Should I use another component to display this text... and if so, which one? Thanks!

*Edit1: the top (yellow and white) smiley is the one of the pivot item, the red and transparent one are the textblocks. It's basically the background that I want to have in color, not the foreground:*

[image]

*Edit2: I just tried to use a TextBox instead of a TextBlock and the icon appears in color... it slowly starts to hint toward a TextBlock problem...*

**_Edit3: It still doesn't work, but at least I have found a way to go around the problem. See [here for the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726243/border-fail-to-size-to-textblock).**

Answer (score 0):

Use Foreground property to define color of the text. Like in the example:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#x1F636;" Foreground="Navy" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @wpfnoop but I want to change the background, not the foreground. I edited my question after you posted your answer to make this more obvious.